# Ignore undefined variable beloning to third party package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to integrate bluesnap payment gateway into a react/ts project. I've included their hosted javascript into my public/index.html and have proceeded with the integration within a component, but on compiling I'm getting the error of

`'bluesnap' is not defined  no-undef`

I've tried to supress the error with `ts-ignore`

```
// @ts-ignore
    bluesnap.hostedPaymentFieldsSubmitData((callback: any) => {
```

However it's still not liking that I'm calling bluesnap without defining it. The bluesnap is defined though within the public/index.html head

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/web-sdk/4/bluesnap.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by appending `window.` ie:
`window.bluesnap.somefuction`